FIrebase-Python library pyrebase not downloading photos
I am trying to download a specific picture named 'giuitarplay.jpg' from my Firebase storage bucket but for some reason, the program runs without any errors but no file is getting downloaded.
highlighting the storage. child function where I have written the filename on the cloud which is  guitarplay.jpg and the download function mentioned the path and filename I want to download on my local machine, even though everything matches I can't get it to work, please help. I have also attached the code files and the Firebase storage screenshot (hiding the config details intentionally)
firebase screenshot
import pyrebase

config = {
  'apiKey': "A*******Jju*****",
  'authDomain': "test1-6*****eapp.com",
  'databaseURL': "https://te**1************sia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app",
  'projectId': "tes****5e",
  'storageBucket': "te**********m",
  'serviceAccount': "serviceAccountKey.json"
}

firebase_storage = pyrebase.initialize_app(config)
storage = firebase_storage.storage()

storage.child("guitarplay.jpg").download(path="C:/Users/subha/OneDrive/Documents/HSMS_obj" , filename="nouser.jpg")`

I tried another approach by listfiles() function and iterating through each file using that approach it works and all the files of my bucket get downloaded but still I want to download a specific file using the child function
esp=storage.list_files()

for file in esp:
# if(file=='guitarplay.jpg'):
    print(file.name)
    file.download_to_filename('photo.jpg')
    

Screenshot of the above approach working

Are you getting any errors?  Your code isn't checking for one, so something could be going wrong and you'd never know.  Also we can't see that the object to download actually exists in your storage bucket.  Maybe "guitarplay.jpg" doesn't actually exist in the bucket at all.  Please edit the question to include more debugging details so we can reproduce the issue on our own.

@DougStevenson Thank you for replying I have made some additions on the original question can you please check it out again

@SubhamKanu I had the same issue as you where the program seemed to execute without any errors but the file wasn't getting downloaded. I checked the source code for the download function and that told me a different story from the documentation. I passed the firebase file path instead of the absolute path on the local system to the download function as the first argument. For filename, I passed the path to store the downloaded file. Something like this
